# Discord.py: Is there a way to get arguments for a command using the on_message() function?

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

I'm just programming my own discord bot with python, and I have a kill command. All it does is that when you type `*kill` and mention someone (`*kill @goose.mp4`), it will give you a random scenario on how you kill them similar to the Dank Memer bot. I'm trying to get that ID of the user that was mentioned, which will be the second argument to the function. But I'm stuck. After reading through the API and searching this up multiple times, I've only been given how to get the ID of the author and ping them with the bot, not the person the author mentioned.

This is the code that I am currently using. One of the variables is given a value only for testing purposes.

```
if message.content.startswith('*kill'):
    print("kill command recieved")
    kill_mention_killer = message.author.mention
    kill_mention_victm = 'some guy'
    print(kill_mention_killer)

    kill_responses = [kill_mention_killer + ' kills ' + kill_mention_victim]
    kill_message = kill_responses[random.randint(-1, len(kill_responses) -1)]
    await message.channel.send(kill_message)
```

Comment: Why don't you just use [commands](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html)?

Comment: In the end, what are you trying to accomplish? What are you trying to send back to the chat?

Comment: Basically, the two variables for each person involved are already assigned and so it picks something off the list e.i "User 1 kills User 2" randomly and assigns it as a variable and then sends that variable in the chat.

Comment: That will have to be done with commands. I'll make a post on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you are currently making this command will not allow you to get the arguments. If you're trying to make a command like this: `*kill @user`, then you will need to be able to get the user that was mentioned (which is your question). Here's how you do it:

**First Step**

```py
import discord, random
from discord.ext import commands
```

These imports are very important. They will be needed.

**Second Step**

```py
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='*')
```

This will initialize the `client`, which is used throughout the code. Now onto the part where you will actually make the command.

```py
@client.command()
async def kill(ctx, member: discord.Member):  # This command will be named kill and will take two arguments: ctx (which is always needed) and the user that was mentioned
    kill_messages = [
        f'{ctx.message.author.mention} killed {member.mention} with a baseball bat', 
        f'{ctx.message.author.mention} killed {member.mention} with a frying pan'
    ]  # This is where you will have your kill messages. Make sure to add the mentioning of the author (ctx.message.author.mention) and the member mentioning (member.mention) to it
    await ctx.send(random.choice(kill_messages))
```

That's it! That's how you make a standard kill command. Just make sure to change the `kill_messages` array to whatever messages you would like.

Comment: It's flagging me an error.
'Client' object has no attribute 'command'

Comment: Did you make sure to use the `import`s that I stated at the top?

Comment: Yeah, I can send the entire code in another comment. Might be something I have in there. I deleted my previous code and saved it on a notepad so I don't think anything should be causing it to flag an error.

Comment: So, after just having this code left, it's still raising that error?

Comment: Well I just deleted *everything* but what you sent and it won't work without putting in the token and when I put in the token it flags an error.

Comment: That error is the same one from before, right?

Comment: Yep. It is. I'll try re-typing everything after sending this.

Comment: `import discord, random
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='*')

@client.command()
async def kill(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    kill_messages = [
        f'{ctx.message.author.mention} killed {member.mention} with a baseball bat', 
        f'{ctx.message.author.mention} killed {member.mention} with a frying pan'
    ]  
    await ctx.send(random.choice(kill_messages))
client.token=('token')`

That's what is there. It's a bit messy, sorry.

Comment: I see that you are having `client.token('token')` at the end. Shouldn't that be `client.run('token')`?

Comment: Yeah, I just edited that and now It's doing nothing at all. I'm running this on repl.it if that matters at all, and it just runs and then stops right after.

Comment: Do you think you can invite me to the repl? I can help there.

Comment: I'd much rather just talk on a platform like discord, or whatever you prefer and share images and such there as it'd be much easier.

Comment: Ah, okay. Friend me: IPSDSILVA#1849

Answer (score 0):

```
if message.content.startswith('*kill'):

    #Mentioned or not
    if len(message.mentions) == 0:
        #no one is mentioned
        return

    pinged_user = message.mentions[0]
    killer_user = message.author
    kill_messages = [
        ...
    ]
    await ctx.send(random.choice(kill_messages))
```

here I just used [message.mentions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.mentions) to find if any valid user is mentioned in the message or not and if mentioned! all the mentions will be in `message.mentions list` so i took the first mention of the message by `message.mentions[0]`. then you can do anything with the mentioned user object.