# I'm trying to write a discord bot using python but i got no responses from the bot :'(

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I have tried to make a discord bot using python but thing is that the bot does not respond...
So I just restarted from 0 and made this little code :

```
import discord

bot = discord.Bot()

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("  -----------------")
    print("  H2H - Here 2 Help")
    print("  -----------------")
    print(" ")
    print("--> by ItsMoonlight_#3415")

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.lower() == "ping":
        await message.channel.send("pong")



bot.run('my_incredible_token')
```

(i use a .bat file to start the bot. in the .bat there is

```
@echo off
py H2H.py
pause
```

and this work, i can see the "on_ready" text.)

But the bot STILL DOESN'T WORK !!

[proof xD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfLRy.png)

My goal is to make a bot with simple commands (like /mute, /help, /clear, etc...).

I tried to make the "ping-pong" command which is very simple to see if the bot works, and it does not...

Help meeeee :'(

Comment: `discord.Bot` is not a  thing in discord.py, but you mentioned that the `on_ready` text works so you're probably using a fork of some sorts. Please tag your post accordingly. Also, it doesn't work because you don't have the message content intent enabled.

Answer (score 0):

close you are but its not `discord.Bot` but rather `commands.Bot`

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.bot()

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("  -----------------")
    print("  H2H - Here 2 Help")
    print("  -----------------")
    print(" ")
    print("--> by ItsMoonlight_#3415")

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.lower() == "ping":
        await message.channel.send("pong")



bot.run('my_incredible_token')
```

Comment: Hello @McBrincie212 ! Thanks for your comment, but... I got an error. I have copied the exact same code as the one you have send me but this happend :
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1041305891745574922/1042008925035298816/error.PNG

Comment: Wait like DRag's answer says, go to the discord developer portal and check if message content intent is enabled, if not enable it then refrence ``intents = discord.Intents.default()`` and then ``intents.message = true`` as well as `bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="prefix", intents=intents)`

Answer (score 0):

I feel as if you're trying to create a **command**. What you're doing is called an event. It triggers when something happens, in this case its when a message is sent.

I actually was in this same position when I started creating my discord bot. Here is [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65634607/discord-py-is-there-a-way-to-get-arguments-for-a-command-using-the-on-message) which should solve your answer.

Answer (score -1):

### ****You were so close but there were a few issues:****

- To access `message.content` you will need to enable the message intent.
  To do this, head over to [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications) and click on your bot. Then go to the bot slide and copy these settings [image]
  After that head over to your code and add the following piece of code above the `bot = commands.bot()`:

> `intents = discord.Intents.default()`

> `intents.message = True`

You should also change `bot = commands.bot()` and add your desired prefix where it says `YOUR_PREFIX`

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="YOUR_PREFIX", intents=intents)
```

Once you have completed all of these steps your code should look like this:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="YOUR_PREFIX", intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("  -----------------")
    print("  H2H - Here 2 Help")
    print("  -----------------")
    print(" ")
    print("--> by ItsMoonlight_#3415")

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "ping":
        await message.channel.send("pong")



bot.run('my_incredible_token')
```

Comment: @ItsMoonlight if this was a valid solution please mark the answer as the solution thanks